# Cannot use pg_dump, command not found

Tags: postgresql

I currently have two databases running in production. One a master and the other a slave. I use streaming replication. I'm looking into using pg_dump and sending the file over to amazon S3. I already know how to perform the logistics of all that. However, I can't seem to run pg_dump.

When I run this command:

```
pgdump -U django_login django_db -Fc > db.backup
```

I receive the following response:

```
No command 'pgdump' found, did you mean:
 Command 'pg_dump' from package 'postgresql-client-common' (main)
```

So I checked to see if I did have postgresql-client-common installed. To check, I ran:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-client-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
postgresql-client-common is already the newest version.
postgresql-client-common set to manually installed.
```

So I know I have it installed. I ran the command again:

```
pgdump -U django_login django_db -Fc > db.backup
```

and received the same response. I'm currently running postgresql 9.1. What kind I do to fix this problem?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP can't read the information provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> No command 'pgdump' found, did you mean:  Command 'pg_dump' from
>   package 'postgresql-client-common' (main)

The command is `pg_dump`, not `pgdump`.

It's okay, it's Friday, and you probably need a beer or three. :)

Comment: wow! I didn't even notice! ahaha yeah just had a beer ahaha thanks a lot man!